# skype distant voice isn't getting port redirection

Tags: c#, skype

It worked earlier with SKYPE4COMLib 1.0.31 but now I am working with SKYPE4COMLib 1.0.33 and it doesn't seem to redirect the distanct voice to a port. I am trying to manipulate the incoming voice and I see that the original along with the manipulated voice get heard.

```
call.set_OutputDevice(TCallIoDeviceType.callIoDeviceTypeSoundcard, "");
call.set_OutputDevice(TCallIoDeviceType.callIoDeviceTypePort, InPort.ToString());
```

Any help is appreciated.

OS: Windows 7 and 
Skype: v4.2

Thanks.